# Overlaying graphics

Tags: c++, graph, overlay, root-framework

I am trying to create a "smart" multigraph using root cern. What I mean is, showing a root frame that has, for example, 2 buttons. Button A and button B. When I press button A, the graphic A appears, and if I press button B, the graphic B overlays the A one. If I press B again it disappears. Is it possible?

Thank you in advance.

I have tried to see the particularities of the "Multigraph" object in the library root, but haven't found any that could match what I wanna do.